# Как связать событие DOM-элемента и объект JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ооп

Простой пример, я кликаю на некий блок на веб-странице и мне нужно, чтобы объект JS, не связанный с этим DOM-элементом (не BOM этого элемента), понял, что нам нужен именно он.
Т.е.

```
<div class="square"></div>
```

Имеем DOM-элемент
Теперь в JS
Имеем объект:

```
var obj = {
    print: function() {
        console.log("Hi, I've been called!");
    }
};

$('.square').click(function() {
    ...Нужно каким то образом вызвать именно obj.print, т.к. подобных объектов и DOM-элементов имеется очень много подобных...
};
```

Решением служит case, но если прописывать так, то выйдет слишком много кода. Так же существует вариант написать функцию с аргументом в виде нужного объекта и на нужном событии вызывать свой объект, но это так же не слишком кратко выйдет. Есть ли какие-нибудь средства в JS, чтобы сделать это более обобщенно и кратко?

Comment: почему просто не вызвать `obj.print()`?

Comment: может потому что я написал, что объектов и элементов много в проекте? не только obj используется

Comment: в примере ты никак не разделяешь для какого из элемента нужно вызывать obj. Поэтому вполне подходит просто вызов `obj.print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), для того чтобы привязать что угодно к чему угодно.

```js
const relations = new Map();

// Объекты, которые вы хотите связать
const objects = [
  {text:"button1"},
  {something:"button2"},
  ["button3","related","array"],
  45 // или не объекты, не важно)
];

// Ключом является DOM элемент
click = e => console.log(relations.get(e.target));

// Привязываем одно к другому
objects.forEach( (object, index) => 
    relations.set(document.getElementById(`b${index}`), object)
);

// навешиваем обработчики
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => b.onclick = click);
```

```html
<button id="b0">0</button>
<button id="b1">1</button>
<button id="b2">2</button>
<button id="b3">3</button>
<button id="b4">4</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может я не совсем понял вас но делегирование событий должно помочь.
Вот тут можно почить как это работает.
https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: Интересно что предложенный ответ выше тоже использует делегирование, почему ему минус не влепили? Слов нет...

Comment: а где в ответе выше делегирование?